# Additional functions added to a class cause a segfault when class is created as a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-ptr

This really has me stumped.

We have a class with a dozen or so getters and setters defined, that take a mix of types (QString, int, bool) for the various member variables. I'm currently adding a new set of functions and variables for some additional data, everything builds fine however when I run the code and it creates a new instance of that class as a `boost::shared_ptr`, then I immediately get a segfault in `in QBasicAtomicInt::deref (this=0x0) at /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.1/include/QtCore/qatomic_i386.h:132`.

I can take it further as well, if I add just the getter and the variable, it'll no longer segfault. If I change the variable to a bool instead of a QString, it'll work, however if I change to a std::string it'll still segfault in the same place which is even weirder as the variable is no longer a Qt one. If I create a new instance of the class without it being a `boost::shared_ptr` it's fine, no problems at all. The functions aren't used internally, or externally in the class yet.

Comment: Did you try to re-run qmake? Or rebuild the whole project? It might be the case that you added some header and qmake didn't update the dependency. Seems like incompatible compilation units when linking them.

Comment: I've tried the clean-rebuild route, as I figured it might be some weird compilation issue.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Turns out trashing the directory and rechecking out the code fresh actually solved it, so I'm guessing there's something that `ant clean` wasn't trashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

I simply create a variable in a class and when try to use then cause segmentation fault and I was going crazy!

My environment is similar: A software using Qt on Linux write in C++ language.

So I clean the project and rebuild and then did work fine!

StackOverflow saves!

Answer (score 1):

Trashed the directory and repulled the code, rebuild and it works. I don't know why, I'm guessing the clean process wasn't properly cleaning something out.